# How to Store Multiple Select Values in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel, multi-select

So my problem is that if i try to save only one value like "Location in the layout" of a post it works, but the moment i am saving an array I'm getting something like ["value 1" , "value 2"] in the DB, therefore it cant be read and in the CRUD-Controller there is no data saved when i am editing.everything works perfectly except the value i am getting from the data. I would appreciate any help, methods or alternatives

edit.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label>Select Post Location</label>
                                <select
                                    class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible"
                                    multiple=""
                                    data-placeholder="Select Locations"
                                    style="width: 100%"
                                    tabindex="-1"
                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                    name="post_locations[]"
                                    id="post_locations"
                                >
                                    <option value="TopBox-GR" @if ($post->post_locations == "TopBox-GR") selected @endif>TopBox-GR</option>
                                    <option value="TopBox-C3" @if ($post->post_locations == "TopBox-C3") selected @endif>TopBox-C3</option>
                                    <option value="TopBox-C4" @if ($post->post_locations == "TopBox-C4") selected @endif>TopBox-C4</option>
                                </select>




</div>
```

home controller

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = post::where([['status',1], ['post_locations','TopBox-GR']])->get();
    return view('user.blog',compact('posts'));
}
```

and view:

```
        <div class="topbox-c4">
            @foreach ($posts as $post)
                <a href="{{ route('post',$post->slug) }}">
                <div class="image-topbox-c4-container">
                    <img src="{{ Storage::disk('local')->url($post->image)}}" />
                </div>
                <div class="text-topbox-c4-container">
                    <h3>{{$post->title}}</h3>
                    <p>
                        {{$post->subtitle}}
                    </p>
                </div>
                </a>
            @endforeach
        </div>
```

post.controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'title'=>'required',
        'subtitle'=>'required',
        'slug'=>'required',
        'body'=>'required',
        'image'=>'required',
        'post_locations'=>'required',
    ]);

    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $imageName = $request->image->store('public');
    }

    $post = post::find($id);
    $post->image = $imageName;
    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->subtitle = $request->subtitle;
    $post->slug = $request->slug;
    $post->post_locations = $request->post_locations;
    $post->body = $request->body;
    $post->status = $request->status;
    $post->tags()->sync($request->tags);
    $post->categories()->sync($request->categories);

    $post->save();

    return redirect(route('post.index'));
}
```

Comment: btw. if i only save 1 value then the name in edit.blade.php would be without square brackets, but i need an array. should i make a whole controller for this like category? if yes how can i display it in the homecontroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should get selected locations in $selectLocations variable and all locations in $allLocations variable for edit.blade.php

In edit.blade.php, you can display like this:-

```
@foreach($selectLocations as $value)
<select class="form-control" name="post_locations[]" multiple=''>
    <option value="">Select Location</option>
    @foreach($allLocations as $val)
        <option @if($value['id'] == $val->id) {{ 'selected' }} @endif value="{{ $val->id }}">{{ $val->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
@endforeach
```

Comment: So should i make a whole make a whole controller for location? What should i write in the HomeController, where i retrieve the data. sry i am new in laravel

Comment: No, you don't need to create a whole controller for location. Just run query for location and get result in variable. On other end, You can get that particular locations which you stored in db while adding new post. After getting both result, passed it on edit.blade.php and then use my previous code

Comment: ok i will try ur method, but could take months cuz my whole project was delete :(

Comment: The OP asks for a way to store and retrieve multiple values. This example just creates a grouped option list? I don't think this should be accepted as an answer.